# Passing a string into custom isolate scope directive with two way binding needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a simple Angular custom isolate scope button directive that needs to use two way data binding so things can be updated dynamically.

```
scope:{
      buttonLabel: "@?",
      buttonIcon: "@?",
      buttonClass: "=?",
      ngDisabled: "=?",
      onButtonClicked: "&?"
  },
```

This works great for dynamically updating ng-disabled and button-class when the values are defined in the developer's controller but when a static value is defined it only works as follows:

```
 <dropdown-button button-label="click me" button-class="'secondary'"></dropdown-button>
```

Given that I need the two-way data binding, is it at all possible for me to do something like:

```
 button-class="secondary"
```

Without the ' ' there.

From what I've seen online it looks like the single quotes are needed. Just wanting to confirm on this either way. If the user needs the single quotes its not the end of the world.

Thanks

Comment: If you will have on your scope a variable named secondary it will take the value of that variable abd will put it in the attribute. So if you will have for example scope.secondary = "secondary" you could write button-class="secondary". If you just need it as a hardcoded string theb you should use @.

Comment: Ok yea so that would be the same as doing this.class = "secondary" and then doing button-class="ctrl.class", which works now. Just curious if I was missing something trying pass in a hard coded string: button-class="secondary" using "=" for isolate scope

Comment: No, but I think if you write something hardcoded as string in the attribute you should take it as @ so you won't have to do things like " 'secndoary' ", and just write "secondary" :)

Comment: Right but if I use "@" then I lose the two way binding to dynamically change the button class, which is a requirement. If I didn't need the two way binding then I definitely would do that.